# How to make EditText multiline programmatically

Tags: android

I need to make EditText with 3 lines by default (using code not XML).

```
EditText txt = new EditText(this);  
txt.setHint(o.getText());
txt.setSingleLine(false);
txt.setLines(4);
txt.setMinLines(3);
txt.setMaxLines(5);
txt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#98def8"));
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params2.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, lastID);
r.addView(txt, params2);
```

However it makes only EditText with one line.

I tried adding height in pixels as well but it did not make any difference. It could only decrease height but not increase it more than one line.

Any ideas why this may be happening?

**EDIT:**
It seems that my question was slightly misleading. I am trying to get this through code:
[image]
Note that three lines of text can be seen on this EditText.

Comment: `txt.setMaxWidth(40)` try setting the max width.

Comment: Not sure what you are seeing/expecting but even at 3 lines when you start typing you'll just see 1 line and it will be centered. Try adding `txt.setGravity(Gravity.TOP);` if you want the content to start at the top.

Comment: I want to have element that spans three lines initially. Meaning I need to see three lines of text while I type in this element.

Comment: You'll have to set the height programmatically by multiplying the text height by 3

Comment: And if you want it to expand to 5 lines as it fills up, add a keypress listener. You're probably better off extending TextView.

Comment: @Snailer I already tried setting height programmatically but it remains one line all the time. I want it to be three lines initially and eventually I will use your second comment to increase it as it grows. But unfortunately I can not get these 3 default lines to be shown as I only get one line.

Comment: I've copied your code and I get three lines. Post more of your XML, it must be the parent/container or something else in your layout that is causing problems. What is `r` for example?

Comment: I also tried copy pasting your code in my app which also adds edit text programmatically.  I see 3 lines of edit text.  I will try creating a layout file with the multi-line edit text and try to inflate it and add it just to see how things work then.

Comment: @KenWolf r is instance of RelativeLayout. There is no XML for this element as it is dynamically created.

Comment: What are the layout params for `r`? What is `lastID?` I really think it would help if we got the full picture here. We're trying to help and you're teasing us with only showing the parts you think are relevant when perhaps it's something else. :)

Comment: @KenWolf layout params were to blame. I accidentally made height of the relative layout fixed while I was doing something else. Apparently it was just enough to show one line and not more. that is why I could shrink the size of my EditText but could not increase it. Thank you all for help.